# I want to implement the horizontal image slider with three.js

Tags: image, three.js, slider, glsl, shader

I want to implement a horizontal image slider in three.js.

This is the example of a vertical slider.
I want to implement the following image. (horizontal slider). [This is the example of a horizontal slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyez3.png).

[image]

```
vertexShader() {

    return `
        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying vec3 vPosition;

        void main() {
            vUv = uv;
            vPosition = position;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }   
    `

}

fragmentShader() {

    return `
        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying vec3 vPosition;

        uniform sampler2D tex0;
        uniform sampler2D tex1;
        uniform float divider;
        uniform float zoomFactor;
        uniform bool hidden;

        void main() {
            float dividerWidth;
            if (hidden) {
                dividerWidth = 0.0;
            } else {
                dividerWidth = 0.03 / zoomFactor;
            }

            if (vPosition.x > divider + dividerWidth) {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex1, vUv);
            } else if (vPosition.x < divider - dividerWidth) {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, vUv);
            } else {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
            }

        }
    `
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to text the `y` component of the texture coordinate rather than the `x` component of the vertex coordinate. The components of the texture coordinates are in range [0.0, 1.0]. Hence `divider` has to be value in range [0.0, 1.0], too:

```c
vec4 texColor0 = texture2D(tex0, vUv);
vec4 texColor1 = texture2D(tex1, vUv);
vec4 sliderColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);

float limit0 = divider - dividerWidth;
float limit1 = divider + dividerWidth;

gl_FragColor = vUv.y > limit1 ? texColor1 : (vUv.y < limit0 ? texColor0 : sliderColor);
```

Comment: Hi, Rabbid76. Thank you for your kind answer. Could you explain how to show the horizontal slider in the middle of two images?

Comment: @happybear0320 The slider is in the middle of the image when `divider = 0.5`

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I look forward to your continued help.